# Windows server 2012 r2 network - Cannot access another server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a strange situation on a brand new Windows Server 2012 R2 (std) server.

I installed it, everything was fine, and I put it in the network. The whole network is with STATIC IPs; no DHCP. 
There's a firewall that act as router/firewall/DNS.

I have another 2012R2 server, with SQL installed, and a bunch of 2008R2 server.

If from the new server I connect to the others 2008R2 servers, everything is fine: network shares, rdp...
Network speed is optimal (local network)

If from the new server I connect (using ip address or hostname) to the "old" 2012R2 server, I have a LOT of problems:

- **sql server management studio** opens and get stuck on "EXPANDING..." on the server or on the databases list. After about 90 secs, an error appears:
  "The specified network name is no longer available"
  [image]
- File shares doesn't work; it gets stuck randomly after the 1st/2nd folder
- RDPing the "old" server doesn't work (it opens the conection and gets stuck on the black screen)

Absolutely no errors in event log; neither on client, neither on server.

Everything else on this network is working fine... 
Network discovery is enabled on both servers.
I tried to disable the TaskOffload on the NIC

Even more strange: I tried to change the local IP address, and everything worked fine for a minute! Then the problem was back.

Comment: SQL: did you add a firewall rule to allow access (on the sql server)? Did you check other network ports - the file share / rdp issue looks like this is a lower level issue and it could be a faulty component. Did you rule this out? Duplicate MAC address?

Comment: Yes: any other server can access SQL server, but just for test I completely disabled the firewall; no antivirus is installed. It happens with all of the 4 NICs, no duplicate MACs

Comment: This totally smells like it is not a SQL server issue but something is wrong on a raw network level (possibly physical). Not sure how to proceed from here, though.

Comment: just to have asked for it: did you check if there's a duplicate mac address?

Comment: yes; checked it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok; the solution was simpler than I expected. I lost a few days, then I tried to completely re-install the HP support pack / service pack for proliant.

That solved the problem.